# Using a sass variable in an @each loop

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a little overview for all the colors we use in our corporate identity. All our colors have been defined in _settings-colors.scss, and the only reason I need this bit of css is for the library, where the colors need to be listed.

What I have now is as follows:

```
$colors-brand: color-brand, color-brand-40, color-brand-60, color-brand-70;

.prfx-color {
    display: block;
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;

    @each $color in $colors-brand {
        &--#{$color} {
            background-color: #{'$'+$color};

            &::after {
                content: '$'+$color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These color-brand variables are set in another file which I'm including in this scss file.

The code above outputs this:

```
.prfx-color {
  display: block;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.prfx-color--color-brand {
    background: $color-brand;
}
.prfx-color--color-brand::after {
    content: "$color-brand";
} [...etc]
```

What I'm after however, is this:

```
.prfx-color--color-brand {
    background: #00ff11; // don't worry, brand is not actually this color
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the $color-brand variable isn't interpreted as a sass variable anymore, but is a literal value. I need the #hheexx that this variable refers to!

All the solutions I've found so far consist of using two lists, or a key-value pair. In my situation these variables have already been set once, and I want a solution where I don't want to have to manually edit the library if the colors change.

Is this at all possibe, or am I too greedy here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And I realized I overcomplicated it. You don't need any extra functions because the **@each** is designed to work with maps and iterating over multiple values.

```
$cool: blue;
$mad: red;

$colors: (
  cool: $cool,
  mad: $mad
);

.prfx-color {
  @each $key, $val in $colors {
    &--#{$key} {
      background-color: $val;

      &::after { content: "$#{$key}"; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is so nifty, it's beautiful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map.
Here's a [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7b734c017d396d1624ae98ca01c696a4) playground for you.

```
$cool: blue;
$mad: red;

$colors: (
  cool: $cool,
  mad: $mad
);

.prfx-color {
  @each $color in map-keys($colors) {
    &--#{$color} {
      background-color: map-get($colors, $color);

      &::after { content: "$#{$color}"; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That. Is. Awesome. Thanks! 
I had shoveled that solution onto the heap of "having to redefine all the colors again", but this actually works beautifully! Do you know why Angular parses the variables doing it this way, and not while using my earlier technique? Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: Glad it helped. It's not Angular, it's SASS. You were trying to compile SASS variable names, but SASS doesn't do that. It only compiles variable values.
So I made a map, where the key is the same name as the variable, without the $. The @each loops over the map keys to create the class name, the map-get uses the key to pull out the value, and I'm interpolating the key (not the variable) for the content(prepending a $ in the content string so it's the same as the variable name.
Check out the SASS functions: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'm using Angular in another project and got the terms mixed up, my bad!